# Isekai manga where the main character is a prince with a water element sword and owns many elemental magic items

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for an isekai manga where the main character is born a prince. Sometime later, he owns a sword, which increases his water element power.

Later on, he owns *many* items that increase his elemental magic powers.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Kizoku Tensei: Megumareta Umare kara Saikyou no Chikara ga Eru](https://animanga.fandom.com/wiki/Noble_Reincarnation)* (AKA *Noble Reincarnation ~ Blessed With the Strongest Power from Birth*)?

> Born as the thirteenth prince, Noah was originally in a position
> removed from the imperial succession, so he freely passed his time in
> the fief granted to him. However, the Crown Prince died before the
> Emperor. The imperial succession would be fairly contested among the
> remaining princes. Noah, being the strongest despite living freely,
> overwhelmed the other princes and eventually became the Emperor with
> the most power in the world.

Originally a light novel, but adapted into a manga. The main character has water skills that are very high.

[image]

His brothers gift him a sword that can channel water powers.

[image]

Comment: Also the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245886/23243